# C# LINQ Query / Projection from FormCollection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dynamic form which I cannot use MVC's binding with. When I post this FormCollection to my controller, simplified, I have the following data in the form collection:

```
public ActionResult Foo(FormCollection coll)
...
  coll["Data0Key"] contains "category" 
  coll["Data0Value"] contains "123" 
  coll["Data1Key"] contains "location" 
  coll["Data1Value"] contains "21" 
  coll["Data7Key"] contains  "area"
  coll["Data7Value"] contains "test"
  coll["SomethingElse"] contains "irrelevent"
```

.. I have an unknown number of these and would like to create key-value pairs from the seperate key and value objects in the collection

I have been attempting along the lines of;

```
    var settings = coll.AllKeys
        .Where(k => k.StartsWith("Data"))
        .ToDictionary(k => k, k => coll[k]);
```

which gives me a dictionary of:

```
Data0Key, category
Data0Value, 123 
Data1Key, location 
Data1Value, 21
Data7Key, area
Data7Value, test
```

What I would really like to have is a collection of key value pairs structured like;

```
 category, 123
 location, 21
 area, test
```

Is what I am trying to achieve possible at all, or do I need to find a different approach?

Comment: How is a dictionary any different from a collection of key value pairs?

Comment: Forgive my terminology, I'm fine with a dictionary, it is the structure I am struggling to achieve.

Comment: I just read your question again and I see what you mean now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to only iterate over the "DataxKey" parts, then look up the values. Something like:

```cs
.Where(k => k.StartsWith("Data") && k.EndsWith("Key"))
.ToDictionary(k => coll[k], k => coll[k.Replace("Key", "Value")]);
```

This assumes that every "Data0Key" also has a "Data0Value" matching pair, otherwise it's going to dereference a key that doesn't exist from `coll`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a relatively straightforward LINQ query:

```
var data = new Dictionary<string,object> {
     ["Data0Key"] = "category" 
,    ["Data0Value"] = "123" 
,    ["Data1Key"] = "location" 
,    ["Data1Value"] = "21" 
,    ["Data7Key"] =  "area"
,    ["Data7Value"] = "test"
,    ["SomethingElse"] = "irrelevent"                 
};
var kvp = data
    .Where(p => p.Key.StartsWith("Data") && (p.Key.EndsWith("Key") || p.Key.EndsWith("Value")))
    .Select(p => new {
        Key = p.Key.Substring(0, p.Key.Length - (p.Key.EndsWith("Key") ? 3 : 5))
    ,   IsKey = p.Key.EndsWith("Key")
    ,   p.Value
    })
    .GroupBy(p => p.Key)
    .Where(g => g.Count(p => p.IsKey) == 1 && g.Count(p => !p.IsKey) == 1)
    .ToDictionary(g => (string)g.Single(p => p.IsKey).Value, g => g.Single(p => !p.IsKey).Value);
foreach (var p in kvp) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", p.Key, p.Value);
}
```

Here is a line-by-line explanation of what is done:

- First, irrelevant items are filtered out by ensuring that only `"Data"` prefixes are kept, and that the suffixes are `"Key"` or `"Value"`
- Next, group key is extracted by removing `"Key"` or `"Value"` suffix; the `Value` is added to the list, along with `IsKey` flag indicating if an item was a key or a value
- Items are grouped by the group key (`"Data0"`, `"Data7"`, etc.)
- Each group is checked to contain exactly one key and one value; incomplete groups are discarded
- Finally, groups are converted to a dictionary of key-value pairs.